# Adding rigged mesh to other rigged mesh

Tags: rigging, armature, bones

I have a rigged model of a head that I created in its own Blender file. I have a body that I created in another Blender file separately.

How would I be able to add the head to the body rig so that the head can essentially be a part of the body rig, but contain all of the armature and bones that it had when it was separate? I also want the head the move with the body rig accordingly as you expect a head to do, along with controls for the next which control the rotation and position of the head.

Comment: You can join rigs together with cmd+J or windows+J